# turn a variable into filename for HTML

Tags: javascript, html, object, variables, filenames

```js
var filename2 = "PDFxx.pdf";
```

```html
<object data=filename2 width="800" height="500"></object>
```

in JavaScript, I like to assign a var filename2, equals to "PDFxx.pdf" etc.

data=filename2 never works, but data="PDFxx.pdf" works fine.

Wondering how to accomplish that. Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the `<object>` via JavaScript and inject it into your document

```js
const filename2 =
  "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf"; // "PDFxx.pdf";
const obj = Object.assign(document.createElement("OBJECT"), {
  data: filename2,
  width: 800,
  height: 500,
});

document.body.append(obj);
```

```css
object { border: 1px dotted; }
```

---

Alternately, query the element and set its `data` property

```js
const filename2 =
  "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf"; // "PDFxx.pdf";
  
document.querySelector("object").data = filename2;
```

```css
object { border: 1px dotted; }
```

```html
<object width="800" height="500"></object>
```